# Push bulk data to linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am looking to automate a bulk transfer of hundreds of thousands of rows between a local and linked server.

When certain events take place, I need to copy the rows from the local to the remote server. My preference is to use TSQL because this will be happening inside a stored procedure.

I have already considered using Select... Into, but as the event which starts this process is located on the local server, obviously I can't select into a linked server.

I want to avoid BCP due to the difficulty of automating it from within a stored procedure (I don't even know which tables are going to be copied, this is all determined at run time.

Is there a way to perform a bulk insert to a linked server from within TSQL?

Answer (score -1):

The `BULK INSERT` command provides the same functionality of bcp only from T-SQL code so you can easily call it from a stored procedure:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx